# NLOG creating debug.txt file when minlevel = "Info"

Tags: nlog

I am not very familiar with NLOG, so I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction to solving this problem. I don't want NLOG to create a debug.txt file. I thought simple updating the minlevel to "Info", would solve it, but it does not.

Here are the settings in my app.config file that point NLOG:

```
    <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog" />

    <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" autoReload="true">
    <variable name="applicationName" value="TheNameOfMyApplication" />
    <include file="\\<PathToNlogConfig>\NLog.config" />
    </nlog>
```

And in my NLog.config file in the rules section:

```
        <logger name="Name.Space.Apps.*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="consoleapps"  final="true" />

<logger name="*" minlevel="Info" writeTo="fileOut" />
```

What else do I need to configure to stop this debug.txt file from being created?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it. Turns out we were using a library to log to NLOG, and NLOG was grabbing the namespace from that library, and hence hitting a different rule.